# iOS UIView animation (animationWithDuration:) with multiple options

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to implement a `UIView` animation block with `animationWithDuration` and multiple options. It is working fine except it only seems to use one of the options I specify instead of all three. Is there a limit to the number of options I can specify or a limit on certain combinations of options?

Below is my code. "starRotator" is a `UIImageView` in a `UIView` that I'm rotating. I tried wrapping the options in parentheses, but that didn't work either. It seems to only take the `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` option and ignore the other two.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:30.0 
                      delay:0.0 
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat | UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     starRotator.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI);
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){ }
 ];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you notice that two of the constants you're using as options contain the word “Option”, but one doesn't?

The correct option constant for a linear curve is `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`, but you used `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been banging my head against the wall trying to figure this out. It always helps to have a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 2):

That code is fine, except that you want to use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear` instead of `UIViewAnimationCurveLinear`. The latter is for use with UIView's old `+setAnimationCurve:` method.

Try changing that and see if you have any more luck.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful too, but Rob beat you to it. Thanks!

Comment: @Justine, yes he did. I never got the Golden Banner of Defeat... Hmm.